# Strange results when trying to check String value type

Tags: ruby, rspec, metaprogramming

I've got a class to encapsulates mime types for communicating with an external system.
here is the part of the class that is relevant for the issue.

```
module Types
   class MetaType
      def self.validator(&block)
         define_singleton_method :is_valid?, &block
      end
   end

   class Float < MetaType
      validator { |v| v.is_a? Numeric }
   end

   class String < MetaType
      validator { |v| v.is_a? String }
   end


   Map = { :Time => Float, :Float => Float , :String => String }

   def self.get_type(name)
      name = name.intern

      raise ArgumentError, "Unknown type #{name}" unless Map.has_key? name
      return Map[name]
   end
end
```

Here is the spec

```
describe Types do
   context "When calling get_type with 'Float'" do
      subject { Types.get_type('Float') }
      it "should validate a float" do
         expect(subject.is_valid? 3.5).to be_true
      end
   end
   context "When calling get_type with 'String'" do
      subject { Types.get_type('String') }
      it "should validate a string" do
         expect(subject.is_valid? "tmp").to be_true
      end
   end
end
```

The output of the spec

```
Types
  When calling get_type with 'Float'
    should validate a float
  When calling get_type with 'String'
    should validate a string (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Types When calling get_type with 'String' should validate a string
     Failure/Error: expect(subject.is_valid? "tmp").to be_true
       expected: true value
            got: false
     # ./tmp/type_error.rb:37:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The code doesn't pass for the string.
I've tried within the validator function of the metaclass to `puts val.is_a? String` but that did prints false? 
When i try `puts "tmp".is_a? String`i have true which is what I expect...

The code works with int, float, bool, hash, but i can't get it to work with String and i do not see any error.

I can't get around for that issue, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

 Thank you

Comment: What is "simothing", "bu"? I don't think "As you can see", "i", "... ???", "Thx" is the correct mode to ask things to someone.

Comment: I'll try to reformulate my question - my english not so good but i'll do my best ;)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I'm almost sure that there is a better way.

Comment: The lib is an interface to pilot an external system. When comunicating with it i will need to convert to it's format the types as it expect it, or to read from it converts back the type to a ruby exploitable format. Here you only have part of the class. I mainly have two other methods (:adapt and :convert) to handle the conversion back and forth - The aim to do metaprogramming is that I do have many MetaType descendance, and to avoid repeating myself, it is a great tool. Everything works except the verification for a String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a name clash going on here.

```
validator { |v| v.is_a? String }
```

In this case `String` is not what you think it is. It's `Types::MetaType::String`. And, of course, value `"tmp"` is not of this type. You want to refer to top-level core class `String`, like this:

```
class String < MetaType
  validator { |v| v.is_a? ::String }
end
```

Comment: indead that was it -thanks a lot for your quick reply - To precedes a word with '::' is a way of calling types at the 'root level' (doesn't know how ewactly to put it) ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, this how you refer to top-level constants.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time ;)